# In a string replacements how we use '/r' modifier

Tags: perl

I need to increment a numeric value in a string:

```
my $str = "tool_v01.zip";

(my $newstr = $str)  =~ s/\_v(\d+)\.zip$/ ($1++);/eri;
#(my $newstr = $str) =~ s/\_v(\d+)\.zip$/ ($1+1);/eri;
#(my $newstr = $str) =~ s/\_v(\d+)\.zip$/ $1=~s{(\d+)}{$1+1}/r; /eri;

print $newstr;
```

Expected output is `tool_v02.zip`

**Note:** the version number `01` may contain any number of leading zeroes

Comment: Hint, `my $newstr = $str =~s/...//r;` or `(my $newstr = $str) =~s/...//;`

Comment: @Сухой27: `my $newstr = $str =~s/(\d+)/$1+1/er;` thanks its working but preceding zero `0` lost...

Comment: it should be `tool_v02.zip` getting output `tool_v2.zip`

Comment: you're not formatting `$1+1` so of course it'd lose the preceding zeros

Comment: @ChrisTurner: That's why I am asking how to do this.

Comment: @ssr1012: Your question asks how to use the `/r` modifier, not how to retain leading zeroes after the arithmetic has been applied.

Comment: @Borodin: In my question clearly registered this line `Note: preceding 0 might be 0..n times.`

Comment: @Borodin: That is not a main point however that is optional preceding zero `0..n` which I have mentioned in my question and it can be understand clearly that zero is available `n` times. If zero is not required then why I should I mentioned in the note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this question has anything to do with the `/r` modifier, but rather how to properly format the output. For that, I'd suggest [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

```
my $newstr = $str =~ s{ _v (\d+) \.zip$ }
    { sprintf("_v%0*d.zip", length($1), $1+1 ) }xeri;
```

Or, replacing just the number with zero-width [Lookaround Assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions):

```
my $newstr = $str =~ s{ (?<= _v ) (\d+) (?= \.zip$ ) }
    { sprintf("%0*d", length($1), $1+1 ) }xeri;
```

**Note:** With either of these solutions, something like `tool_v99.zip` would be altered to `tool_v100.zip` because the new sequence number cannot be expressed in two characters. If that's not what you want then you need to specify what alternative behaviour you require.

Comment: `_v \K` is more efficient than `(?<= _v )`, though it requires Perl 5.10+

Answer (score 0):

The bit you're missing is `sprintf` which works the same way as `printf` except rather than outputting the formatted string to `stdout` or a file handle, it returns it as a string. Example:

```
sprintf("%02d",3)
```

generates a string `03`

Putting this into your regex you can do this. Rather than using `/r` you can use do a zero-width look ahead (`(?=...)`) to match the file suffix and just replace the matched number with the new value

```
s/(\d+)(?=.zip$)/sprintf("%02d",$1+1)/ei
```

Comment: This doesn't handle *"Note: preceding `0` might be `0..n` times."*

Comment: @haukex n wasn't defined in the question so I picked 2...but I'm sure the OP is capable of choosing a number that fits so that all filenames have the same sized number

Comment: @Chris: I think you're misunderstanding the question. *"preceding 0 might be 0..n times"* is poor English, but it means there may be any number of leading zeroes. It *doesn't* mean that `n` will be provided as part of the data, and you can't just *"pick 2"*.

Comment: @Borodin so you don't think the question is asking how they format a number consistently to fit any numbers within a given range, with potentially optional preceding zeroes?

Comment: @Chris: I think the OP has confused themselves. The subject line and the following few lines of code, show attempts to understand the `/r` modifier and nothing more. That is one question, and is fine as it stands. But then a footnote tries to involve zero-padding, which is completely irrelevant to the main thesis about the `/r` modifier. Questions here should be focused and complete, but people often carry an expectation that their needs should be serviced first. The truth is that a good question and its answers are the target: together they will help many more than just the OP.

Comment: @Chris: *"so you don't think the question is asking how they format a number consistently"* I must ask what you think it's about given a subject line *"In a string replacements how we use '/r' modifier?"* Are you suggesting that no one should be constrained in any way, and a subject line like *"$$$s in bitcoin & repair your own uber sys like a pro"* should also be fine as long as the question goes on to mention in a **note** that they have memory errors?

Comment: It seems like the OP is asking two questions at the same time. Is there a precedent for this situation in SO?